# how to push data as a object in my array and how to set object in state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to return a object to my array but it return number values in arry

```
const mappingFunction = (values: any) => {
    values.forEach((reason: any) => {
      const selectedReasons: any = [];
      if (reason?.isChecked === "false") {
        selectedReasons?.push(reason);
      }
    });
    setSelectedReasons(values);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable before the loop, not for every item:

```
const mappingFunction = (values: any) => {
  const selectedReasons: any = [];
  values.forEach((reason: any) => {
    if (reason?.isChecked === "false") {
      selectedReasons?.push(reason);
    }
  });
  setSelectedReasons(values);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `selectedReasons` inside your loop which will create a new instance on every iteration. You also pass `setSelectedReasons` to the values that the function takes in.

You could use the `filter` method to get only the values where the `reason` is `false`.

```js
const mappingFunction = (values: any) => {
  const filteredValues = values.filter(
    (reason: any) => reason?.isChecked === "false"
  );
  setSelectedReasons(filteredValues);
};
```